# Configure Magento Inside another Magento folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I want to configure Magento site inside sub folder but parent folder also have Magento site.

For example:

> app/
>   skin/
>   media/
>   js/
>   **beta/**
>   .../
>   .../

I want to configure Magento inside beta folder but due to parent magneto .htaccess, beta URL doesn't work. Only home page loads but further links are not working.

here is my site URL

http://tradeplumbing.co.uk/

and

http://tradeplumbing.co.uk/beta (only home page work If click on any link this redirect to main site)

Comment: In the beta directory's Magento .htaccess have you uncommented the `RewriteBase` so that it is `RewriteBase /beta/` ?

Comment: yes I have uncommented and give RewriteBase /beta/ but after this only home page work but further links not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the paths in the core_config_data table?

You need to change web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to be you new path with a trailing /.

If you have multiple stores you will need to modify them too.

Also if you have full paths in the database for the templates, JS and CSS files, rather than relative paths, you will need to modify these database fields in core_config_data too:
web/unsecure/base_skin_url
web/unsecure/base_media_url
web/unsecure/base_js_url

Once all that is done you will need to delete the cache (/var/cache) and any session files (/var/session) files to force the files to be regenerated.